# LAMP: retrieving international (i.e. chinese) characters from an URL

Tags: escaping, character, lamp

I am trying to retrieve a string of characters from an URL, i.e.:

```
http://www.domain.com/mystring
```

using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

This works pretty well with ASCII characters, but doesn't with international characters such as chinese, etc as the string gets escaped i.e.

```
テスト
```

becomes

```
/%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88
```

Any help on how to address that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution :

```
urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```